# Combine two list data into single list C#

Tags: c#, linq

So i have following two list using linq.

```
List<One> one= A.Common
               .Join(B.Common,
                a => a.ID,
                b=> b.ID,
                (a, b) => new One
                {
                  ID = b.PID,
                  Name = b.PCName,
                  LastName = a.LName
                }).ToList();

List<One> two = (from c in D.Options
                 select new One
                 {
                   MainName = c.mName
                 }).ToList(); 

 List<One> sn = one.Concat(two).ToList();
```

I am concating both list. But when i debug i am getting MainName as null in `sn list`.

How do i get data from both list in single list??

Comment: Have you checked what value you are getting for MainName in `two`? Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: The first collection, You are not setting MainName... Is it ok?

Comment: @MairajAhmad I have property MainName in Class one

Comment: @dmyoko I cannot set MainName in first collection,because i have to Fetch it from Options

Comment: @RahulSingh I am getting correct values in two. But just not in sn :(

Comment: Maybe you are confusing concat (that simply concatenates two lists) with zip (which combines the data from two lists in a new single list), are you not?

Comment: I think you want to merge both lists, get `MainName` from `Options` and set it to list one's `MainName`. Is it what you want?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking... if that is the case, instead of Concat, the method you're looking for is Zip.

Comment: @Shaharyar Yup. i want to get mName from option and set to MainName of class One

Comment: Very unclear what you mean "in single list"... Your `Concat` put them in single list, but it looks like you want something different... Sample input/output would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
var sn = one.Zip(two, (x, y) => new One{
  ID = x.ID,
  Name = x.Name,
  LastName = x.LastName,
  MainName = y.MainName
});
```

Comment: I got the problem but didn't know how to solve it using LINQ :)

Comment: That is reducing count of original items

Comment: It's important, though, to make sure the two lists are properly organized... that is the elements are in order, and there's no one missing (unless you want to discard the missing ones).

Comment: Probably because the two lists have different number of elements.

Comment: Here is an example. http://www.dotnetperls.com/zip. Read **Uneven source data** heading.

Comment: Lets say you have 10 elements in "one" and 8 elements in "two".

The result will be a list of 8 elements... combined in the order both lists were created. So, the first of one will combine with the first of two, the second of one with the second of two... (that kinda makes sense, once LINQ can't just guess what is missing in both sides...)

Comment: So there is no way i can get all item from one and two?

Comment: Well, you can make sure that both lists are equivalent, by filling the gaps. I'll assume that this ID property can be used to identify the Pairs... you can  guarantee that both lists have a pair to each ID... and it is important to be sorted... so you will get the full result, but, as expected... some data will be missing for some elements

Comment: What about make a single join as you make with A.Common and B.Common?

Answer (score 0):

You want the MainName property assigned for all the list values in **List ONE** ?

As from above code concatenation will join two list and the MainName will be not set for list one elements.

```
one.Concat(two)
```

Above line will just concat the both lists to one list elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LINQ [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) and [ToList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) methods:

```
var mergedList = YourFirstList.Concat(YourSecondList)
                    .Concat(YourThirdList)
                    .ToList();
```

Edit:

```
one.Concat(two).Select(g => g.Aggregate((p1,p2) => new One 
{
    ID = p1.ID,
    Name = p1.PCName, 
    LastName = p1.LName,
    MainName = p2.mName
}));
```

more efficient ways to do this - the above will basically loop through all the entries, creating a dynamically sized buffer.

```
var mergedList = new List<One>(YourFirstList.Count +
                               YourSecondList.Count +
                               YourThirdList.Count);
mergedList.AddRange(YourFirstList);
mergedList.AddRange(YourSecondList);
mergedList.AddRange(YourThirdList);
```

AddRange is `special-cased` for `ICollection<T>` for efficiency.

You can use the `Zip` method.

```
one.Zip(two,(o1, o2) => new One() 
{ 
   ID = o1.ID, 
   Name = o1.PCName, 
   LastName = o1.LName, 
   MainName = o2.mName 
});
```